# Iterate over CSV file and compare strings?

Tags: python, cs50

So I'm working on CS50 Problem Set 6 (pset6) problem, DNA. I kinda get the logic on how to approach the problem, but I can't figure out the code. As this is a problem I should solve on my own, I'm not asking for a exact code solution, just some hints on libraries, etc.

My approach is: iterate over the first row of the database, in this case `argv[1]`, and search for the STR's (Short Tandem Repeats) one at a time in the `argv[2]` or sequence file to then compare. Then I would compare the number of times in a row a STR's shows in the DNA sequence with each individual.

Link to [pset6](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/)

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

if len(argv) != 3:
    print("Incorrect amount of command line arguments")
    exit(1)

with open(argv[1],'r') as database:
    pass

with open(argv[2],'r') as sequence:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out "csv.reader":
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader

> A short usage example:
>
> ```
> import csv
> with open('eggs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
> ...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
> ...     for row in spamreader:
> ...         print(', '.join(row))
> Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
> Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
> ```